# How to make a counter for a mini game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

I was wanting to make a game for my mini-web project and i came across these codes to help me make a game, the objective of this game is to match the correct picture to the correct placement( in this case North, Center, South). i got the validation working, i was wondering if it was possible to create like a prompt box when the last picture is dropped into the correct box. In addition i also have a timer, i was wondering if it was possible to print the time on the prompt when the user completes the game. I am only allowed to use HTML, CSS and JavaScript Only.

```js
//Timer//
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();
//End of Timer//

//Start Game//
// add event handler
var addEvent = (function () {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + type, function () { return fn.call(el, window.event); });
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  }
})();



// inner variables
var dragItems;
updateDataTransfer();
var dropAreas = document.querySelectorAll('[droppable=true]');

// preventDefault (stops the browser from redirecting off to the text)
function cancel(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}

// update event handlers
function updateDataTransfer() {
    dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');
    for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
        addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData('obj_id', this.id);
            return false;
        });
    }
}

// dragover event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'dragover', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // little customization
    this.style.borderColor = "#fff";
    return false;
});

// dragleave event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'dragleave', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // little customization
    this.style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    return false;
});

// dragenter event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'dragenter', cancel);

// drop event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'drop', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // get dropped object
    var iObj = event.dataTransfer.getData('obj_id');
    var oldObj = document.getElementById(iObj);

 // validate the placement of the image
 if(this.id !== oldObj.dataset.dropTo) {
        return false;
    }
    // get its image src
    var oldSrc = oldObj.childNodes[0].src;
    oldObj.className += 'hidden';

    var oldThis = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        oldObj.parentNode.removeChild(oldObj); // remove object from DOM

        // add similar object in another place
        oldThis.innerHTML += '<a id="'+iObj+'" draggable="true"><img src="'+oldSrc+'" /></a>';

        // and update event handlers
        updateDataTransfer();

        // little customization
        oldThis.style.borderColor = "#3e8bc6";
    }, 500);

    return false;
});

//End of Game//
```

```css
/* Page layout styles */
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.Game-border{
 height:40px;
 width:100%;
 background-image:url('../../Media/Main/mbg2.png');
}
/*Timer*/
.timer{
 height:auto;
 width:25%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 7px solid #3e8bc6;
 font-size:2.5em;
 letter-spacing:5px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:1% auto;
 padding:1.5% 2% 1.5% 2%;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px yellow;
 
}


/*End-Timer*/

/* Photo Gallery styles */
.gallery {
    margin: 3% auto 4%;
    width: 840px;

}

.gallery a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
 height:135px;

    -khtml-user-drag: element;

    /* CSS3 Prevent selections */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.gallery a img {
    border: 8px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    /* CSS3 Box sizing property */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /* CSS3 Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
}

/* Custom CSS3 rotate transformation */
.gallery a:nth-child(1) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(2) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(3) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(4) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(5) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(6) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(7) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(8) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(9) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(10) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(11) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:nth-child(12) img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.gallery a:hover img {
    z-index: 5;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /* CSS3 transform rules */
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.gallery a.hidden {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.albums {
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 840px;
}
.album {
 text-align:center;
    border: 3px dashed #64a2d1;
 font-size:1.2em;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 0 0 2px yellow;
    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
}
.album a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 56px;
    margin: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;

    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;

    /* CSS3 Prevent selections */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.album a img {
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    /* CSS3 Box sizing property */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* CSS3 transition rules */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    /* CSS3 Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #444;
}
```

```html
<article class="timer">
   <h1 class="realtimer"><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
  </article>
  
  <!-- End-Timer -->
  
        <div class="albums">
            <div class="album" id="drop_1" droppable="true"><h2>North</h2></div>
            <div class="album" id="drop_2" droppable="true"><h2>Centre</h2></div>
            <div class="album" id="drop_3" droppable="true"><h2>South<h2></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
  
        <div class="gallery">
            <a id="1" draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_1"><img src="../Media/Game/1.jpg"></a>
            <a id="2" draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_3"><img src="../Media/Game/2.jpg"></a>
            <a id="3" draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_3"><img src="../Media/Game/3.jpg"></a>
            <a id="4"  draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_1"><img src="../Media/Game/4.jpg"></a>
            <a id="5"  draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_2"><img src="../Media/Game/5.jpg"></a>
            <a id="6" draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_2"><img src="../Media/Game/6.jpg"></a>
            <a id="7"  draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_1"><img src="../Media/Game/7.jpg"></a>
            <a id="8"  draggable="true"data-drop-to="drop_3"><img src="../Media/Game/8.jpg"></a>
            <a id="9" draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_1"><img src="../Media/Game/9.jpg"></a>
            <a id="10"  draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_2"><img src="../Media/Game/10.jpg"></a>
            <a id="11"  draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_1"><img src="../Media/Game/11.jpg"></a>
            <a id="12"  draggable="true" data-drop-to="drop_3"><img src="../Media/Game/12.jpg"></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the part below:

```
// drop event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'drop', function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // get dropped object
    var iObj = event.dataTransfer.getData('obj_id');
    var oldObj = document.getElementById(iObj);

    // validate the placement of the image
    if(this.id !== oldObj.dataset.dropTo) {
        return false;
    }
    // get its image src
    var oldSrc = oldObj.childNodes[0].src;
    oldObj.className += 'hidden';

    var oldThis = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        oldObj.parentNode.removeChild(oldObj); // remove object from DOM

        // add similar object in another place
        oldThis.innerHTML += '<a id="'+iObj+'" draggable="true"><img src="'+oldSrc+'" /></a>';

        // and update event handlers
        updateDataTransfer();

        // little customization
        oldThis.style.borderColor = "#3e8bc6";

    if (document.querySelectorAll('.gallery > a').length < 1) {
        alert('Congratulations!\nTime elapsed:' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

I added the code below for the prompt (customize as you please) on the drop event, after the DOM element is replaced.

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.gallery > a').length < 1) {
        alert('Congratulations!\nTime elapsed:' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/gazzb58o/3/).